# Php 5.4 Include / require -- cannot get file path right

Tags: php, include, web, require, filepath

Suppose i have this file:

/Home/user/docs/somewhere/inHere.php

And in this php, i want to require this:

/Home/user/other/well/buried/place.php

I know the difference between an absolute and relative path, but cannot seem to figure out how php wants this to look, i keep getting 'file not found or does not exist'

I am on a hostgator shared web server, if that has any bearing on anything.

Comment: Share some code and project structure

Comment: `include '../../other/well/buried/place.php';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you can get the current folder using `getcwd()`.

Next, you can use `$path = '../../etc'; $realPath = realpath($path)`. It will return false if the path is wrong, and the concrete path without relative `../`'s if it is indeed an actual path.

If you still can't get it, `var_dump($path);` and then copy the path and try to `cd` into it, you should diascover what you are doing wrong at that point.

Comment: I see three different quoting patterns used in these answers (' ', ', and "). Which is correct, and what is the difference?

I'm fairly new to php, so bear with me please.

Thanks you all for fast responses!

Comment: I stick to single quotes, as HTML can have double quotes in the string. When using a variable however, you need with single quotes to come out of the string, like this `$x = 'some string ' . $var;` With double quotes, you can use `$x = "some string $var";`. Just depends what you are doing tbh

Comment: Got this working using realpath() thanks for your help!

Comment: glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Include it using absolute paths.

Either:

```
include '/Home/user/other/well/buried/place.php';
```

or do it relative from where you are, but still absolute:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../other/well/buried/place.php';
```

The magic constant `__DIR__` contains the absolute path to the file it was written in.

If you just do a relative path `include '../../and-so-on'`, the starting point will change if you're including that file in some other file that resides in some other location.

Answer (score 0):

From the file location (somewhere) you have to go upwards (to docs) and another time (to user), and then go inside "other", like this:

```
include ("../../other/well/buried/place.php");
```

There you go.